# How do I make a for loop that has range in it loop back to the top of the loop without changing the range variable? I have code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that makes sure that a stat number is between 1-25 in a range for loop. If the number is bigger than 25 or smaller than 1 or has an invalid input it makes the flag = True, and then it continues. For some reason though it doesn't go back to the stat that had an error, it just moves onto the next one.

I've already tried to use break continue and all that but none if it works.

Here is the code:

```
# checks that only these characters are in a name
def name_characters(input_string):
    allowed_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    
    for char in input_string:
        if char not in allowed_chars:
            return False
    
    return True

`makes sure the number is not higher or lower than 1 or 25`
# makes sure the number is not higher or lower than 1 or 25.
def input_stat_error(input):
    flag = False
    while True:
        try:
            if int(input) > 25:
                e.msgbox("Number is higher than 25, try again", "Error")
                flag = True
                

            if int(input) < 1:
                e.msgbox("Number is smaller than 1, try again", "Error")
                flag = True
                
        
        except ValueError:
            e.msgbox("Invalid input, try again", "Error")
            flag = True

        return None   

# Makes it look a lot better and saves space
import easygui as e

# This is the card catalogue the user starts with
monster_cards = {
    "Stoneling": {
        "strength": "7",
        "speed": "1",
        "stealth": "25",`your text`
        "cunning": "15",
    },
    "Vexscream": {
        "strength": "1",
        "speed": "6",
        "stealth": "21",
        "cunning": "19",
        },
    "Dawnmirage": {
        "strength": "5",
        "speed": "15",
        "stealth": "18",
        "cunning": "22",
        },
    "Blazegolem": {
        "strength": "15",
        "speed": "20",
        "stealth": "23",
        "cunning": "6",
        },
    "Websnake": {
        "strength": "7",
        "speed": "15",
        "stealth": "10",
        "cunning": "5",
        },
    "Moldvine": {
        "strength": "21",
        "speed": "18",
        "stealth": "14",
        "cunning": "5",
        },
    "Vortexwing": {
        "strength": "19",
        "speed": "13",
        "stealth": "19",
        "cunning": "2",
        },
    "Rotthing": {
        "strength": "16",
        "speed": "7",
        "stealth": "14",
        "cunning": "12",
        },
    "Froststep": {
        "strength": "14",
        "speed": "14",
        "stealth": "17",
        "cunning": "4",
        },
    "Wispghoul": {
        "strength": "17",
        "speed": "19",
        "stealth": "3",
        "cunning": "2",
        }
}

# The first screen the user is met with to edit the cards
while True:
    choices = ["Add a new card to the catalogue",
               "Search the catalogue",
               "Delete a card from the catalogue",
               "Output the entire catologue to terminal",
               "Exit the program"]


    input = e.buttonbox("Choose on of the options to edit the catalogue: ", "Monster Card Catalogue", choices)
    if str(input) == "Exit the program":
        exit()


    if str(input) == "Add a new card to the catalogue":
        while True:
            name = (e.enterbox("Enter monster name", "New Monster Name"))
            if name_characters(name):
                break


            else:
                e.msgbox("Invalid characters, try again.")
                continue
    

        monster_cards[name] = {}
        strength = 0
        speed = 0
        stealth = 0
        cunning = 0
        stats = ["strength", "speed", "stealth", "cunning"]
        stats_names = [strength, speed, stealth, cunning]

        # Loops for each stat ****************************************************** NEEEEEED TO FIX. WHEN ERROR IT DOESNT LOOP BACK TO ORIGINAL STAT.
        x = range(4)
        for n in x:
            while True:


                (stats_names[n]) = int(e.enterbox("Enter a number for " + (stats[n]) + " up to 25", "New " + (stats[n]) + "stat"))
                monster_cards[name][stats[n]] = (stats_names[n])
                input_stat = (stats_names[n])
```

please

```
                print(input_stat)
                flag = input_stat_error(input_stat)
                if flag is True:
                    continue

                else:
                    break
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could make a much smaller example. But I'm pretty sure the `if / continue / else / break` sequence can be removed it you use `while flag:` as the loop condition.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to understand this a bit, so if I have any misconceptions about your intentions, please let me know.

I want to mention, firstly, as far as I'm aware, you can't name a variable `input` in python, as that's the name of a function to accept user input during runtime.

To get to your question, `continue` is designed for just that; skipping an iteration. It sounds like you want to prevent the loop from continuing to adjust that value. This can be confusing with a for loop, so you may want to hop to a While loop with a control variable you explicitly increment only when it meets your condition.

This allows you to essentially "redo" the loop while keeping your control variable the same.

Comment: So pretty much my error is that when the user is asked to enter a number and it goes through the fucntion, if there is an error, instead of asking for the original stat that got the error, it instead just +1's onto the for n in x. 

How would I change the for loop to a while loop if that's what's not working. I also don't exactly know what a control variable is and how to implement it.

My bad I am very new to CS in gerenal, but thanks a lot for help

Comment: No worries, you're doing great! A `for` loop is just a form of a while loop. It can be recreated by declaring some variable (let's call it `i`) before the loop, saying `while(i < maxVal)` and doing an `i+=1` at the very end of the loop. However, you can make a condition where the `i+=1` *only* happens when it reaches a condition you're satisfied with, like `if(x > 0 and x < 25)`. This should be closer to what you're looking for